# stats package not found in R

Tags: r, rtools, renviron

I'm really having problems with RStudio.
It had been working fine a few days ago. Then it said I needed the newest version of RTools. I tried to install it but don't think it was successful. However now I can't load anything in R.
I am greeted with the following message when launching RStudio:

```
   Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘stats’ in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...):
 unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.6.3/library/stats/libs/x64/stats.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.

During startup - Warning message:
package ‘stats’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found 
Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : 
  unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.6.3/library/stats/libs/x64/stats.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.
```

I have looked up solutions to this problem and people say to delete /Renviron but I don't know will that mess things up even more.

Here are a few results of things I type into R:

```
> Sys.getenv("PATH")
[1] "C:\rtools40"
> Sys.which("stats.dll")
stats.dll 
       "" 
> Sys.which("make")
make 
  ""
```

I really don't understand what has gone wrong. Can anyone help?

Comment: What's currently in your Renviron file? (it's just a text file). Your version of R and Rtools should match. Right now it seems like you are running R3.6 but are using Rtools 4.0

Comment: @MrFlick when I open up Renviron in R it just says PATH="C:
tools40". Do you have any suggestions what I can do?

Comment: I would try updating your R to the lasted version. You seem to have a mismatch between the two programs at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You accidentally overwrote the `PATH` envvar. Your line in `.Renviron` must be: `PATH="C:/rtools40/usr/bin;${PATH}"` (mind the " and the {}), otherwise you'll lose the R installation path and R will not be able to load the shared library.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following line to the `.Rprofile`

```
Sys.setenv(PATH = "C:/Program Files/R/<your version of R>/bin/x64")
```

The issue seems to result from the R in Rstudio environment cannot find Rblas.dll and Rlapack.dll in the $R_HOME/bin/x64 folder. Copy and paste these two files to where the stats.dll is also work, but I think adding the path is a better solution.

Comment: To make your question more useful to others in the future, please elaborate on why you believe this "is a better solution." Thanks